# Secure downloads without authentication

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, symfony

I would like to create temporary links to prevent direct download of files.

The flow should be this:

user purchase the file, indicating only the email address -> sends an email to that address with the url to the temporary file purchased.

I wish this url is available only for 3 times.

How can I do this?
Using Symfony2 on apache server.

I apologize for the request extremely vague, but I'm going blind and I do not know what to look for to find a way.

Comment: You can safe the url in a database. And count how many times the url exists in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a random key, make a mysql table which contains fileid, key, number_of_downloads.

Every time the user clicks a link to http://www.yourdomain.com/getfile.php?file=blah&key=blahblah you can update the table number_of_downloads. If it's < 2, redirect to the file (use php header or symphony's redirect), if it's > 2, give a 404 or whatever...

Comment: I wouldn't suggest redirecting to the file, because that would mean the file would be publicly available (and therefore not particularly secure). Instead, put the file outside of the document root and have the download page echo the contents of the file. You will have to make sure that the file is the only thing echoed (no HTML) and you have to send the content type (something like `header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream")`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be pretty simple (although I don't know much about Symfony2). You'll have a download page that gets a "key" parameter (maybe `/download?key=blahblahblah`). Make a database (or other sort of storage), and whenever you need to generate a download link, have your code make up a key and store it in the database. Each key could also have a number attached to it for the number of times it can still be used, or alternatively an expiration time. The download page would make sure the key is still valid, and if so serve up the file.

Edit: Here's an example of serving a file through a PHP script:

```
// this may need to change depending on the file type
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
// this makes sure the downloaded file doesn't get named "download.php"
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=stuff.zip");
// and this sends the file
echo file_get_contents("/path/to/stuff.zip");
```

Edit again: Actually, [this](http://php.net/readfile) is probably a better way.